# Gnome: How to open a very very large log file?

Tags: linux, vim, gnome, gedit

I've got a log file about 157Gb (Gnome). It's a very large file and nor gedit nor vim can open it.
Alternatively I want only to see the last 20 lines and I can't back it up because of space storage limitations.
Any solutions?

Comment: you need to use stream so it wont attempt to load full file to RAM. try `tail -20 file.log` to view last 20 lines. Or if you want to constantly keep track of last 20 while the new lines are added to file then use `tailf file.log`

Comment: While I doubt this will be of use to the OP, it is perhaps worth noting for future users: beyond the usage of `tail`, `less`, etc. for viewing a massive log file as-is, if you find yourself in this scenario, you **should** enable log-rotation and it probably would be a good idea to use the `split` command to separate the existing log file into smaller chunks. Among other things, some file-systems will not even support files as large as the OP's log file (e.g., ext3, ext4, and FAT32).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use stream so it wont attempt to load full file to RAM.

Try command `tail -20 file.log` to view last 20 lines.

Or if you want to constantly keep track of last lines while the new lines are added to file then use `tailf file.log`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the previous post, tail command works fine if you want to see only the last 20 lines;
But if you want to really the navigate/search contents of the file, without loading the entire file into memory, try the 'less' command;  Most of the vi navigation commands also work with less;  You will be only be able to view the contents of the file and will not be able to edit.